# Разные ajax спинеры на одной странице

Tags: ajax

Не знаю как реализовать вызов разных блоков спинеров на одной странице от разных ajax запросов. Например один спинер показывается когда подгружаются посты, а другой когда подгружается список.

Есть такой код

```
var $loading = $('#spinner').hide();
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $loading.fadeIn(100);
  })
  .ajaxStop(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
    $loading.fadeOut(100);
    },200);
  });
```